# Algebra of the complex scalar field - complex conjugate of commutation relations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, commutator, complex-numbers

The canonical commutation relations of the complex scalar field $\phi$ are given by

$$[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$
$$[\phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{*}(t,\vec{y})]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$

Since $[\phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{*}(t,\vec{y})]=[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{*}$, the second commutation relation ought to include a minus sign.

Can someone resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: The equation after "Since" is not true. Remember that $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$.

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280928/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$[\phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{*}(t,\vec{y})]$$
$$= \phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}) \pi^{*}(t,\vec{y}) - \pi^{*}(t,\vec{y}) \phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}) $$
$$ =\left( \pi(t,\vec{y}) \phi(t,\vec{x}) \right)^{*}-\left( \phi(t,\vec{x}) \pi(t,\vec{y}) \right)^{*} $$
$$ =[\pi(t,\vec{y}),\phi(t,\vec{x})]^{*}$$
$$ =-[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{*}$$

Comment: Can you show that $ =-[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{\dagger}=[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]$?

Comment: No, because I do not believe that to be true. What I can show is $[\phi^{+}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{+}(t,\vec{y})]=-[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{+}$ - that follows by the same argument as above. Complex conjugation does not make a difference.

Comment: Well, $[\phi^{\dagger}(\vec{x}),\pi^{\dagger}(\vec{y})]=[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})]=i\delta^{3}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$ and $[\phi^{\dagger}(\vec{x}),\pi^{\dagger}(\vec{y})]=-[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{\dagger}$ seem to imply that $-[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]^{\dagger}=[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})]$!!! Doesn't it?

Comment: Why is $[\phi(t,\vec{x}),\pi(t,\vec{y})]=[\phi^{+}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{+}(t,\vec{y})]$?

Comment: Because both of them are equal to $i\delta^{3}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$.

Comment: As $[\phi^{*}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{*}(t,\vec{y})]=i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$, complex conjugation yields $[\phi^{+}(t,\vec{x}),\pi^{+}(t,\vec{y})]=-i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: @failexam I updated my answer.

Comment: Comment to the answer (v2): Consider to mention for clarity what the plus and star notations mean.

Comment: @Qmechanic sometimes, I get confused myself ...

Comment: @failexam I am sorry about the confusion. Please tell me what the difference between your stars and daggers/pluses is...

Comment: @failexam in what I have written so far, * was conjugate transpose and + simple transposition (restricted to the cases where that actually makes sense)